# If I statically link library to exe, will another dll use this link?

Tags: c++, static-linking, vcredist

There are (static?) library *L* - VC++ runtime, a program *EXE*, that uses functions from *L*, and a dll library *DLL*, that also uses function from *L*. *EXE* also uses functions from *DLL*.

On PC there is no C++ redists, I statically linked *L* to *EXE*. *DLL* has not been statically linked with *L*.

*EXE* runs some function from *C*, that uses function from *L*.

Will it fail, and hence I need either to also statically link *L* to *DLL*, or install redistributable package?

---

Specific example:

I have dll library that needs VC redistributables to be installed on the system, as I understand, as bunch of dlls.

I want to run some program, that uses my dll, on PC where VC redist is not installed, and I do not want to attach installation file, I just want my program to run on click.

So the solution is to statically link vc runtime in Visual Studio, but can I link only to exe, and it will share it with my dll, or do I need to statically link dll as well as exe?

---

My thoughts:

I think it will not work because: if vc runtime static link is not turned on in *DLL* project properties in Visual Studio, then, I suppose, in vc headers, imported function will be as variables, with values obtained from `GetProcAddress`, as in plain dynamic linking:

```
some_vcruntime_header.h

#ifndef RUNTIMESTATIC

typedef void (*MEMCOPY)(void *, const void *, size_t);

HINSTANCE vcruntime = NULL;

MEMCOPY memcpy;

vcruntime = LoadLibrary(L"path/to/vcruntime140.dll");

memcpy = (MEMCOPY)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)vcruntime, "memcpy");

#endif
…
```

And if vs runtime is linked statically, then it will not look for the dll, and header will have just a function definition, not as variable:

```
…
#ifdef RUNTIMESTATIC

void memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t);

#endif
```

If my assumption is correct, then by statically linking *L* to *EXE*, the *DLL* without static link of *L* and loaded by *EXE*, still will be searching for dlls versions of vc runtime.

Comment: Your question isn't *entirely* clear to me. The DLL is a separate module from the EXE so it won't 'naturally see' functions that the EXE has in it (from the static library). You need to either link that library also with the DLL or you *could* export the routines from the EXE and import them into the DLL (but that would probably create a circular dependency, if the EXE imports stuff from the DLL). I'm not sure what your issue with redistributable is, though.

Comment: First - rename libraries and executables (apps) like L1, L2, A1, A2. Now it is too hard to understand relations. I am not sure are you asking that the same function is available in static and dynamic library? If yes, it cannot be compiled without some change. It is like you define the same function F1 two times and ask what will happen - compiler will return error.

Comment: Easy solution - from VS project properties go to C++/Code generation and select Runtime `Multi-threaded (/MT)`. This will link statically all necessary and you will not deal with C++ redist. I guess this is what you need and looking for. The executable will run on any (new) Windows without searching for DLLs (other than OS system). If you want to implement your own DLL, the simple solution is "Do not create DLLs. Move all code to EXE." The only reason to do DLL is if you have school homework for DLLs.

Comment: @i486, this is exactly what I am asking, **but**, if dll has static link with purpose not to attach vc redist, then exe also should been static linked with vc redist, and we have two more total program size. I am building C++ gui library and going to distribute it. Without static link it is about 100 kb, with - about 300 kb

Comment: @i486, hah, I wrote my last comment before You update Yours with *The only reason to do DLL is if you have school homework for DLLs*. Now You now it is not the only one. I actually surprised, that user with 6K reputation makes such statements

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd 200KB or 10MB file size is nothing today. And even, bigger size sounds like "more serious" product. Don't worry to add extra 200-300KB for static library.

Comment: @i486, *"200KB or 10MB file size is nothing today"* however I'd want to have the the most lightweight, yet the most powerfull solution. *"bigger size sounds like "more serious" product"*, well, at least as iOS user I completely disagree: there are a lot of apps that are just like a flash lighter, or calculator and weights 100-300 mb. On desktop approximately same.

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd I agree for size and "serious product" but young generation thinks differently. On iOS maybe executables are small but in Windows world they are huge. I don't know why and what is inside - maybe gallery of background images without compression. Recently I downloaded installer with size like 300MB or similar!

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd they probably include a whole framework, or even a browser. (not saying it's a good thing)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**.

It's unknown and not guaranteed to work, unless documentation for A (including its source code) states otherwise. Whole "will it work" depends on what library does.

**Long answer**.

DLL is a separate executable module, which differs from a program by the entry point used. It got secondary entry points - exported functions you use.

If both modules are linked statically with library A, they use separe instances of A's functions and variables. If A contains a singleton or a global variable, each will have own instance.

In fact, this can be abused to create "objects" by loading additional instances at run-time by LoadLibrary. The author of this text did it in past to port Fortran program's functions and common blocks into a C++ program. Then loading and running each instance would not change data in another, less  data copies required and allocated memory would be freed with DLL.

Library can be designed to work around that issue, but it's rare a and it's documented as a supported feature. Some libraries can be compiled as DLLs by design, some have infrastructure that checks if another instance is imported from another DLL. In some cases it's a non-issue because library does not contain own stateful objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience on building static libs, or even just static linking, only dynamic. It is still unclear will it work. Though, I think - no. If in VS dll's project setting I will not set static linking on C++ runtime, then somewhere in code it will search exactly dlls via `LoadLibrary`

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd static library is part of your program. It can exist in your program only as single instance (due to linking process), with names of functions and variables removed from end result. DLL is a _separate_ program and dynamic linking with main one is done via table of exported and imported entities. Essentially making a static library way simpler than a DLL. If you're author of library, make it stateless and you're set at "it will definitely work". All states should be stored in main program.  If you're not, search info or ask the authors this concrete question.

Comment: I meant that, if static linking is not enabled, then, probably, somewhere in vc++ headers for each imported function is written typedef, then function created as variable, and then somewhere obtained from the `GetProcAddress`, from `LoadLibrary`, so my dll will search library as dll somewhere. If static link, then functions are just defined as functions. And in the first case, even if statically link needed libraries to exe, my dll still will be searching them in some directory as dlls

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd you describe manual  .dll loading. The dynamic linking is done somewhat in different way and doesn't use LoadLibrary at all. LoadLibrary\GetProcAddress are user-space interfaces for what I described above.

Comment: *“in different way”* — how exactly?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd After compiling .dll library you also get  a definition file and a static "import library" you use to link with your program. For cimplicity you need a header with function declaration, but it's not necessary same file as in .DLL code, just declarations should be right one with import attribute.  After that OS's loader does the job loading an instance of library, executing  `DllMain()` function and saving function addresses in table. There is no definitions of  function pointers in headers or something. An import table included from static library is all you need.